# calling a method in a smali file using ApplicationContext

Tags: applicationcontext, smali

I want to call a method using p0 ApplicationContext:Landroid/content/Context.
How can I get the ApplicationContext for the class?

I tried calling my method from the init method of the class in order to copy p0, but android failed to verify the class with this.

Any ideas? I will provide more detail if required.

@JesusFreke : More info

### 1 EDITED CRASH

```
10-06 15:43:48.081 14308 14557 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: WFSync
10-06 15:43:48.081 14308 14557 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.zynga.words3, PID: 14308
10-06 15:43:48.081 14308 14557 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter$6: void com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter$6.<init>(com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter, android.content.Context, com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.AppModelCallback, java.util.Date, long, java.util.Date, long, com.zynga.wfframework.remoteservice.IRemoteService$PollType, com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.sync.SyncService$SyncServicePollType, android.content.Intent, int) failed to verify: void com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter$6.<init>(com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter, android.content.Context, com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.AppModelCallback, java.util.Date, long, java.util.Date, long, com.zynga.wfframework.remoteservice.IRemoteService$PollType, com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.sync.SyncService$SyncServicePollType, android.content.Intent, int): 
[0x41] 'this' arg must be initialized 
(declaration of 'com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter$6' appears in /data/app/com.zynga.words3-2/base.apk:classes3.dex)
10-06 15:43:48.081 14308 14557 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter.refreshState(SourceFile:1201)
10-06 15:43:48.081 14308 14557 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.game.GameCenter.refreshState(SourceFile:1144)
10-06 15:43:48.081 14308 14557 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.zynga.wfframework.appmodel.sync.SyncService$1.run(SourceFile:189)
10-06 15:43:48.081 14308 14557 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

### 2 PARTIAL CODE

```
.method constructor <init>(Lcom/zynga/wfframework/appmodel/game/GameCenter;Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/zynga/wfframework/appmodel/AppModelCallback;Ljava/util/Date;JLjava/util/Date;JLcom/zynga/wfframework/remoteservice/IRemoteService$PollType;Lcom/zynga/wfframework/appmodel/sync/SyncService$SyncServicePollType;Landroid/content/Intent;I)V
    .registers 16

    ...

    #@41
    #v0=(Reference,Lcom/zynga/wfframework/remoteservice/RemoteServiceSyncResult;);v1=(Null);p0=(UninitThis,Lcom/zynga/wfframework/appmodel/game/GameCenter$6;);
    invoke-virtual {p0, v1, v0}, Lcom/zynga/wfframework/appmodel/game/GameCenter$6;->onPostExecute(ILcom/zynga/wfframework/remoteservice/RemoteServiceSyncResult;)V
```

Why is p0 not initialised? What can I do to catch it initialised?
Hope you can help. By the way, I fixed the problem in another way, but this relies on an error method in the class being called. I would prefer to find another solution.

Comment: I would recommend you investigate the verification error, to better understand *why* it failed verification. An unexpected failure is the best chance to learn :). When a dex file fails verification, there should be some logcat logs from the verifier with more details about exactly what failed. And in some cases, it may be useful to search through art's codebase for the error code/error message you see in logcat, to find more information about exactly what caused it to fail.

Comment: @JesusFreke please see my update

Answer (score 1):

In a constructor, the `this` argument (`p0`) starts out as uninitialized, and it can't be used until it has been initialized. You must call the superclass's `<init>` method to initialize it.

e.g. if the super class is `Lcom/some/superclass;`, and it has a no-args constructor, you would need to add

```
invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/some/superclass;-><init>()V
```

at some point before you try to use `p0`.

Assuming you're starting out with a working method to begin with, the constructor should already have such an instruction. In which case, you just need to move your method call after it.

Comment: Perfect Jesus. Cheers